# How to execute a stored procedure from button Click - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

I am trying this code but I don't know how to link it to button:

```
Dim rs

Call GetdbConnection()
With cmd
.namedParameters=true
.Commandtext = adCmdStoredProc
.CommandType = "dbo.Up_GetMaxWeightedScores"
.Parameters.Append.CreateParamete("@asof_date",adInteger,adParamInput,   50, asof_date)
.Execute

 End with
 Set rs = cmdObj.Execute    
 %>
```

Comment: What kind of button? Is this Web Forms? MVC? Web API? Web Pages? Did you look up tutorials for working with buttons in your desired framework?

Comment: It is a web form, I have looked up the tutorials and tied this code but it is not working.                                                                                    <button name="btnWeight" id="btnWeight" class="auto-style1" onclick="submitscore()" runat="server">.

Comment: I added the above asp code into a function name submitscore() and calling that at 'onclick'. It is not doing anything.